# With SAS is it possible to XPORT with labels longer than 40 characters?

Tags: sas

I am trying to use SAS 9.2 to create a XPORT file.  One of the lables is over 40 characters long and is truncated on `PROC COPY`.

I have tried both `PROC COPY` and `DATA` to create the `XPORT` file.  Is this possible to resolve or am I out of luck?

```
333        /* Export Dataset */
334        OPTIONS VALIDVARNAME=ANY;
335        /*
336        PROC COPY IN=work OUT=xptout MEMTYPE=data;
337         SELECT MyDataSet;
338        RUN;
339        */

NOTE: PROCEDURE DATASETS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.42 seconds
      cpu time            0.25 seconds


340        DATA xptout.MyDataSet;
341         SET work.MyDataSet;
342        RUN;

NOTE: The variable label {long label} has been truncated to {truncated label}.
NOTE: There were NNN observations read from the data set WORK.MyDataSet.
NOTE: The data set XPTOUT.MyDataSet has NNN observations and NN variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.12 seconds
      cpu time            0.09 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

How sad but this is not possible.  The [XPORT](http://support.sas.com/techsup/technote/ts140.html) format is byte packed based on 80 character blocks.  There is a hard limit of 40 characters in the XPORT variable description for the label.  So while the column its self support 256 characters in the SAS Dataset the XPORT file only supports 40

:o(